# Failed to redirect in react

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-router, components

I have an app component which I want to make a redirection once it lands on it from there if the condition doesn't satisfy and render another component when it finish rendering but somehow when I go to `"path/myURl"` I don't see my `<Home>` component:

```
const App: FunctionComponent<{}> = () => {
  useEffect(() => {
    if (!localstorage.getItem("token")) {
      window.location.replace("/myUrl");
    }
  }, []);

  return (
    <>
      <Route
        exact
        path="/myUrl"
        render={() => <Home />}
      />
    </>
  );
};
export default App;
```

Home component:

```
const Home: FunctionComponent<{}> = () => {
  return <> Hello</>
}
```

index page:

```
class WebComponent extends HTMLElement {
  render() {
    ReactDOM.render(
      <root.div style={{ all: "initial" }}>
        <BrowserRouter>
          <App />
        </BrowserRouter>
      </root.div>,
      this
    );
  }

  connectedCallback(): void {
    this.render();
  }
}
```

Comment: Is `App` rendered within a Router? You can (and should) use route props or `useHistory` hook to do a `history.replace` to redirect. What other Routes are being rendered before "/myUrl"?

Comment: The react-router way of doing this is to either render a `<Redirect />` or push the new url to its `history` object. Also, the `/myUrl` route needs to be inside the main `<Router>`, not in the component that triggers the redirect.

Comment: @DrewReese I dont have any other routes that rendered before "/myUrl"  actually, the page once it land it makes a check if there is a token or not and then redirect thet user to another route

Answer (score 0):

Use react router:

```
class WebComponent extends HTMLElement {
  render() {
    ReactDOM.render(
      <root.div style={{ all: "initial" }}>
        <BrowserRouter>
          <Switch>
          <Route
            exact
            path="/myUrl"
            render={() => <Home />}
          />
          <Route
            path="/-"
            render={() => <App />}
          />
          </Switch>
        </BrowserRouter>
      </root.div>,
      this
    );
  }

  connectedCallback(): void {
    this.render();
  }
}

// Your App component


import { useHistory } from 'react-router-dom'

const App: FunctionComponent<{}> = () => {
   const history = useHistory();

   useEffect(() => {
    if (!localstorage.getItem("token")) {
      history.push('/myUrl');
    }
   }, []);

   // return
}
```

Comment: thank you for the fast response but it says: Cannot GET /myUrl when it redirect me to that path also is there a way where I can make a reload to the page and not using Redirect from react-router ?

Comment: Did you wrap your Route component in a Router provider like in the doc ? https://reacttraining.com/react-router/web/guides/quick-start

Comment: Could you display the index page please ?

Comment: please have a look

Comment: I edit my answer, don't know if it an help like this.

Comment: Or try to move the useEffect logic in WebComponent.

Comment: Hey @Striped again! thanks for your help btw yesterday but I have managed to fix it by removing the query string from my "myUrl" cause it contain something like that "myUrl?page=1&content=2...." so I kept the index.tsx just like "myUrl" and in the app component "myUrl?page=1&content=2...." and that made it work but once I refresh the page it does not work though and cannot find the component to render

Answer (score 0):

Usually there is a better way to redirect in **React** apps. I would use for this purpose [`useHistory`](https://reacttraining.com/blog/react-router-v5-1/#usehistory) hook because you have a function component.

Try as the following:

```
import { useHistory } from 'react-router-dom'

const App: FunctionComponent<{}> = () => {
   const history = useHistory();

   useEffect(() => {
    if (!localstorage.getItem("token")) {
      history.push('/myUrl');
    }
   }, []);

   // return
}
```

Additionally you should wrap the component with `<Router>` and `<Switch>` components as well in order to make it work.

If you are interested in further options for representing different programmatically possible redirect options for React Apps then check out my GitHub repository: 
https://github.com/norbitrial/react-router-programmatically-redirect-examples

I hope this helps!

Comment: didnt work actually and idk what is the reason, did you check my last updates ?

Comment: @A.H You missed `<Switch>` component as I mentioned in my answer, that's needed.